# Is it possible to store fonts in a R-Package?

Tags: r, fonts, package

In R, it is possible to import all fonts registered on your system using the `extrafont`-package. When sharing code among several computers, the installed fonts might differ, however. So it might be practical in some cases to store a specific font in a package which could then be loaded on each computer.

The help file of the `extrafont`-package contains this passage:

> Presently it [the package] allows the use of TrueType fonts with R, and installation
>   of special font packages.

Perhaps, these "special font packages" are what I seek for. I have no idea how to store a font in R and put it in a package (however, I am a little bit familiar with building packages). Perhaps someone can give a sensible hint?

Comment: This package does store two fonts somehow I think: https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/emojifont

Comment: They are in `inst/emoji_fonts/` and the author uses `sysfonts` to load them apparently.